# Windows 7 replacement of Vista's Windows Meeting Space

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

Microsoft Vista came with a free collaboration tool called Windows Meeting Space, which is not included in Windows 7 Enterprise nor can I find a stand alone link to download. Is there a similar tool included in Windows 7 that I'm missing or a replacement Microsoft product (perhaps Microsoft SharedView) that you would recommend? Ideally a tool that is compatabile with our existing Vista Windows Meeting Space users.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking this up a few days ago when I needed to do a few tasks that I used to accomplish with Netmeeting.

Most of the home P2P items have been removed and instead Microsoft seem to be promoting Homegroup for media and document sharing. It looks like the features available in meeting space are no longer available which is a shame.

I guess not a lot of people were using it in Vista and the do not see the need to support it. [SharedView](https://connect.microsoft.com/content/content.aspx?ContentID=6415&SiteID=94) seems to be the only remnant that I can find, which you seem to already know about.

Comment: http://www.computersplace.com/windows-7-%E2%80%93-where-is-windows-meeting-space/windows-7/